# Join 'Day', 'Time' (tblActivity) with 'Responsibility' (tblRoomType)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I join 'Day', 'Time' (tblActivity) with 'Responsibility' (tblRoomType)?

```
create table tblRoomType (
RoomType nvarchar(2) primary key,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsibility nvarchar(20)
)

create table tblActivity (
ActivityID nvarchar(12) primary key,
Name nvarchar(12),
Type nvarchar(3),
ModuleID nvarchar(6),
Day numeric (1),
Time numeric(2),
RoomID nvarchar(8),
constraint fk_moduleid foreign key (ModuleID) references tblModule(ModuleID),
constraint fk_roomid foreign key (RoomID) references tblRoom(RoomID)
)
```

Comment: give us some sample data from your tables. Also include the create table script for tblRoom.

Answer (score 0):

salman2k15, from your post it is not obvious what the link (foreign key) is between tblActivity and tblRoomType. Can you give us more information about all your schemas? I can only speculate based on the schema definitions you've given us, and I suspect there might be a third table involved that may be needed to join tblActivity and tblRoomType.

If I'm speculating, I can assume that tblActivity.Type is the foreign key for tblRoomType.RoomType. HOWEVER, this is unlikely because one of them is nvarchar(2) and the other is nvarchar(3) (but perhaps that's a mistake in the schema definition?). If that is in fact the foreign key, this is how you'd join:

select Day, Time, Responsibility
from tblActivity a, tblRoomType b
where a.Type = b.RoomType

Best of luck.